# Combine elements out of multiple lists?

Tags: python

Given multiple lists:

```
>>> foo = [hex, oct, abs, round, divmod, pow]
>>> bar = [format, ord, chr, ascii, bin]
and  others
```

I complete it with several nested condition

1.retrieve the variable from system

```
>>> dir()
['__annotations__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'bar', 'foo']
>>> [e for e in dir() if '__' not in e]
['bar', 'foo']
>>> mul_list =  [e for e in dir() if '__' not in e]
>>> mul_list
['bar', 'foo']
```

2.obtain each element with nested condition

```
>>> [ e.__name__ for single_list in mul_list for e in eval(single_list)]
['format', 'ord', 'chr', 'ascii', 'bin', 'hex', 'oct', 'abs', 'round', 'divmod', 'pow']
```

How to extract with simple code elegantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about a simpler way, but you should consider accessing `globals` as an alternative to using `eval`:

```
[ e.__name__ for list_name in mul_list for e in globals()[list_name]]
```

Comment: have you try to run this code , because  I am getting error while run this

Comment: @Kallz You need to do `mul_list =  [e for e in dir() if '__' not in e]` first.

Answer (score 1):

frist change

```
mul_list =  [e for e in dir() if '__' not in e]
```

To

```
mul_list =  [e for e in dir() if '__' not in e and isinstance(eval(e),list)]
```

so always get the only list in mul_list

@coldspeed check it

```
>>> foo = [hex, oct, abs, round, divmod, pow]
>>> fred = ['one', 'two', 'three']
>>> jim = [1, 2, 3]
>>> mul_list =  [e for e in dir() if '__' not in e]
>>> [ e.__name__ for list_name in mul_list for e in globals()[list_name]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__name__'
>>> mul_list
['foo', 'fred', 'jim']
```

Comment: `[hex, oct, abs, round, divmod, pow]` is a list of modules. So `e.__name__` works.

Comment: If you want to solve this so it works for this problem, then obviously `['one', 'two', 'three']` and `[1, 2, 3]` should not be used, because they aren't lists of modules.

Answer (score 0):

You can just concatenate lists using the + operator.
So,

```
multlist = []
for e in dir():
    if "__" not in e:
        if type(eval(e)) == type(multlist)
            multlist += eval(e)
```