# Integrate elements in multiple lists into one list

Tags: python, list

Suppose too many lists:

```
fred = ['one', 'two', 'three']
jim = [1, 2, 3]
# and many others
```

I want this `['one', 'two', 'three', 1, 2, 3, ......]` and tried as following codes

```
dir()
output: ['__annotations__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'fred', 'jim']
multiple_list_names = [ e for e in dir() if "__" not in e]
output:['fred', 'jim']
```

then,

```
new_list = []
for name in multiple_list_names:
    for elem in eval(name):
        new_list.append(elem)
print(new_list)
output:['one', 'two', 'three', 1, 2, 3,]
```

How to do it smarter?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45666957/how-to-draw-elements-out-of-multiple-list-to-create-an-uncompanied-one/45667064#45667064 See my answer with `globals`.

Comment: `new_list = [*fred, *jim]`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Found a good dupe. Well, maybe. The OP seems to be asking about concatenation, but then starts doing stuff with global variables and `eval`.

Comment: @ChristianDean I'm second guessing myself. I think OP's intent is to have this work for an arbitrary number of unknown lists. if not confirmed, this will remain shut.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Hmm, yes. I see your point. If that's the case the OP should probably be advised to use a list of lists.

Comment: yes , but about concatenation without copying the variable names already typed in.@ChristianDean